# Process LaTeX math in dynamically loaded answers

Tags: bug, mathjax, answers

When a new answer was posted while I'm writing my own answer, I see a nice notification box, where I can click on a link to load new answers. I just saw a case where the LaTeX code in these new answers didn't get processed by MathJax. It would be nice if that processing could be triggered for the newly loaded content.

Comment: screenshots or a more detailed description of the problem would be very useful in tracking down such a bug.

Comment: @robjohn, I have no screenshot, but the text of the answer had a plain `$\mathbb R^2$` in it, rendered in the normal text font. Reloading the page rendered the math all right. What additional detail would you require? To reproduce this, I guess you could team up with another person, ensuring that you are entering stuff into the composer while that other person posts a reply containing math code. Then you can wait for the notification and click on the link to load that answer, and will hopefully see what I mean.

Comment: I did the very same thing yesterday: loaded another answer while I was composing my answer. However, I did not see this behavior. It sounds as if your browser stalled while processing the MathJax. I have seen this happen, and reloading the page allows the browser to rerender the page. If this happens regularly for anyone, then it should be possible to debug a reproducible case.